# C++ cin returns 0 for integer no matter what the user inputs

Tags: c++

No matter the cin it continues to to output 0 for score. Why is that? I tried returning the "return 0;" but still no go :/

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Variables
int enemiesKilled;
const int KILLS = 150;
int score = enemiesKilled * KILLS; 

int main()
{
    cout << "How many enemies did you kill?" << endl;
    cin >> enemiesKilled;
    cout << "Your score: " << score << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform the multiplication after the user has entered their input:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "How many enemies did you kill?" << endl;
    cin >> enemiesKilled;
    int score = enemiesKilled * KILLS;
    cout << "Your score: " << score << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Uzqw2Q)

Answer (score 1):

You need to recalculate `score` *after* the user has entered a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> enemiesKilled;
score = enemiesKilled * KILLS; // <-- Put the calculation here!!
cout << "Your score: " << score << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`int enemiesKilled;` is initialised to 0 when your program starts.

`int score = enemiesKilled * KILLS;` is calculated at the same time.  Since `enemiesKilled` is 0, it is also 0.

As noted in the other answers, you need to calculate `score` at runtime instead.

Comment: Are you sure that `score` is calculated at compile-time? `enemiesKilled` is not a constant. I think it would be initialized at run-time before `main` is entered.